# Create object after thread creation vs passing object on thread creation

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any differences between creating object **after** thread creation (approach A below) and creating it in current thread and pass it to new thread (approach B)?

Approach A:

```
public class AppA {

    private A app;

    public void run() {
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            this.app = new A();
        };
        Thread workerA = new Thread(runnable);
        workerA.start();
    }
}

public class A {

    private final EventDispatcher dispatcher;

    A() {
        this.dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AppA appA = new AppA();
    appA.run();
}
```

Approach B:

```
public class AppB {

    private B app;

    public void run() {
        EventDispatcher dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            this.app = new B(dispatcher);
        };
        Thread workerB = new Thread(runnable);
        workerB.start();
    }
}

public class B {

    private final EventDispatcher dispatcher;

    B(EventDispatcher dispatcher) {
        if (dispatcher == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AppB appB = new AppB();
    appB.run();
}
```

- `App` object created in single thread.
- `app.run()` called from single thread.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no difference if you don't use that same object for something else (pass it to different thread maybe). It's like basic OOP - you should define your object in the narrowest scope where you will use it. Being a thread is no difference. So if you want to use it outside the thread - create it outside. Otherwise create it in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of taste mostly. But in approach `A`, you have a better encapsulation. If you don't need access to the dispatcher outside of the thread, that it is more preferrable to create it inline.
However if you do need access, or you create multiple threads that need a single dispatcher, injecting it through the constructor is better.

Ergo: it depends...

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the differences are purely stylistic.  But I would argue that version A is better because:

- version A is simpler
- the object that is being passed to the constructor (in version B) is not used / needed within class `AppB` where you are creating it ... so the additional complexity in version B has no real purpose.

But assuming that you *need* to pass a parameter from the parent thread to the child thread *via* the `Runnable`, then it is definitely better to do it the version B way than other ways.

For example, suppose that you want to pass a `StringBuilder`<sup>1</sup> from the main thread to the child thread:

- The version B approach doesn't require any synchronization to be performed to effect the transfer. There is a *happens-before* between the call to `Thread.start()` in the parent thread and the corresponding call to `Runnable.run()` in the child thread.  That ensures that the child thread will see the state of the `StringBuilder`<sup>2</sup>
- If the `Runnable` executes a callback to the parent thread to pick up a `StringBuilder` potentially created by the parent thread after the `start()`, then you need to use some form of synchronize; e.g. a synchronized method.
- If the parent thread is going to actively pass the `StringBuilder` after the `start()` call (e.g. by calling a setter on the `Runnable` object), then you need both synchronization AND some kind of coordination; e.g. the child thread may need to wait for the object to be passed to it.

---

<sup>1 - This class is chosen for this example because it is not thread-safe.</sup>

<sup>2 - This assumes that the "main" thread doesn't change the buffer after calling `start()`!</sup>